# Jmeter value to variable in string

Tags: jmeter

How do i replace a variable defined in a file (a.xml) after the file is read into Jmeter ?
eg.  a.xml has a content.

`<Shipment Action="MODIFY"   OrderNo="${vOrderNo}" >`

The entire file is read into a string using
str_Input=${__FileToString(/a.xml)}

In the Jmx file, a http Request is made to get output from a webservice as 
Using Xpath Extractor the value of OrderNo is read into a Variable  vOrderNo.

Now, wanted to use the value of variable vOrderNo in the str_Input.. ? How do i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using beanshell (~java) code from any jmeter's sampler which allows beanshell code execution - [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) e.g..

The following works:

```
import java.io.*;

try
{
    // reading file into buffer
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\test.xml"));

    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    data.append(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
    in.close();

    // replacing stub with actual value
    String vOrderNo = vars.get("vOrderNo");
    String temp = data.toString().replaceAll("\\$\\{vOrderNo\\}", vOrderNo);

    // writing back into file
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\test.xml"));
    out.write(temp);
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    IsSuccess = false;
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
```

This code doesn't require read file into string via ${__FileToString(...)}.
As well, you can combine both methods.

Comment: Thanks Alies... but i was wondering if i could use in-built functions of Jmeter rather than having to write code ... did some research and I think this might work.. but not sure how to make it happen .. any idea  ?   ${__eval( ${__FileToString(../ReferenceImplementation_1/Input_ChangeOrder.xml)})}   Or  __evalVar  or __V  ???            Also, another reason to avoid writing java code here is .. since, the XML might have more than 1 variable defined in it at runtime.. so i wont be able to write java code to replace the specific variables..

Comment: i think this approach should work for my case tooo  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172297/is-it-possible-to-include-jmeter-variables-in-values-obtained-from-csv?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Alies ur Nov 2011 reply  in that thread worked for me...  ${__eval( ${__FileToString(a.xml)})}

Comment: Nice if so. I simply find using beanshell code-snippets a bit more powerful and flexible, but this is only a matter of preference.